# Rejected edit seems correct

Tags: support, suggested-edits, rejected-edits

I previously made [this edit suggestion](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/15565885)
as the question was relating to MS Access which requires nested joins to be bracketed and this was not included in the answer so it would not work. Other than that I didn't change anything else about the post but it was rejected by 3 different people as they said it deviates from the original intention of the post. Am I missing something?

Comment: They most likely didn't look at the answer fully and just looked at the review which does look like you're trying to deviate from OP's code, but after reading the comments below the answer, this edit _should_ have been approved IMO. Out of interest, why are you only now inquiring about a review made 5 months ago?

Comment: Thanks George. Do you think I should re-raise it. Perhaps making it clearer in my comment the reason for the edit? Also, I was just randomly browsing my profile which got me thinking about it so that's why it's from a while ago lol

Comment: It's down to you if you want to re-raise it, but if you do, yes, make the comment clearer. **Glorfindel** has given an excellent answer, so follow that advice in the future :)

Comment: *but after reading the comments below the answer* In addition to what Glorifindel said, if the comments on a post support you making the edit then also include that in your edit summary. We can't actually see comments when reviewing edits so a "based on comments on post [made change]" prompts people to open the post to check.

Comment: If the answer given isn't correct, the best thing to do is to downvote and to post your correct answer.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

While editing code in an answer isn't so much of a problem as it is in questions, you should always specify *why* you make this change.

> Bracketed nested joins

just specifies *what* you did, not why.

> Bracketed nested joins, because otherwise the query doesn't compile in MS Access

would be much better.

---

Because suggested edits are reviewed by people who are not likely to be [access-vba](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/access-vba) experts, they might just think you're changing formatting/indentation, which is largely a matter of personal preference, and leads to rejection of the kind:

> This edit does not make the post even a little bit easier to read, easier to find, more accurate or more accessible. Changes are either completely superfluous or actively harm readability.

Comment: Ok, that makes sense. I will re-raise the suggestion with a clearer explanation

Answer (score -2):

Quoting @Glorfindel answer

> suggested edits are reviewed by people who are not likely to be access-vba experts

Those people **should** normally click <kbd>Skip</kbd> button. Even vba experts *may* click it if they are not 100% sure and don't want to spend time on checking it precisely.

It's unfair to edit answers like this, one should start with the simple comment first

> This will cause error ... you have to put bracers ...

maybe author of the answer will read it and will fix it by himself. And even if not - your comment is there, it will get upvoted and then someone will fix the snippet.

High reputation will [let you](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/edit) to edit answers in place, just wait for it, if **you are** an expert - you'll get it and will be able to avoid *queue noobs* ;) I am assuming that participating in editing means you also provide correct answers, asking good questions, etc. which all provide you with reputation.